# Discontinue a recruitment process

Tags: recruitment

So I am in the final stage of the recruitment process and the presentation is scheduled in a couple of days. Over the weekend, I received an offer that I accepted.

Ideally, I would have waited for this final stage before accepting the other offer but the offer is from a company that ticks all my boxes and any delay would have left a terrible impression as well as caused delays in the agreed start date, which is not too far away.

How do I deal with the upcoming final stage presentation? Cancel it by informing the HR Manager? Inform the HR Manager of the accepting another offer? Just go ahead with the final stage and see what happens? Something else?

Answer (score 6):

Just call HR, say "Thank you for your consideration but I have accepted an offer from another company".

Don't waste their time if you have already made up your mind.

Comment: If they had already decided on another candidate, you would tend to want them to politely tell you as an applicant that the positions was filled, not continue to interview you and lead you on.  Polite consideration and not wasting their time in the opposite direction is equally appreciated.  Some will tell you go through for the practice. Having been on both sides, interviewed people I knew had already made another choice, and been interviewed when I learned another person had already been chosen and accepted, I cannot disagree more. Neither side deserves to have their time wasted.